# Complexity of conic optimization problems

Tags: computational-complexity, convex-optimization, cones

I am interested in bounding the computational complexity of the interior points method for solving a generic conic problem of the form
\begin{equation}
 \min_x \left\{ c^T x : \mathcal{A}x-B\in\mathbf{K} \right\},
\end{equation}
associated to cone
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{K} = \mathbf{S}_+^{k_1} \times \ldots \times \mathbf{S}_+^{k_p} \times \mathbf{L}_+^{k_{p+1}} \times \ldots \times \mathbf{L}_+^{k_{p+m}}.
\end{equation}
This exact formulation appears in [this book](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Lect_ModConvOpt.pdf), $\mathbf{S}_+^{k}$ is the cone of $k\times k$ symmetric positive-semidefinite matrices, and  $\mathbf{L}_+^{k}$ is the Lorentz or second order cone with $k$ variables.

This book in fact provides insights on how many steps are required by this kind of problem in page 278 as it states,

> The canonical barrier K for the cone K given by (Cone), by definition,
>   is the direct sum of the canonical barriers of the factors.

However, the analysis on **the computational complexity for computing each step** is only given for particular instances: linear programs (LP), second-order cone programs (SOCP) and semidefinite programs (SDP).

Is the computational complexity of a conic problem including linear constraints, second-order cones and semidefinite cones, known?